# How can I know if browser notifications are blocked by Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, push-notification, notifications, settings

My web app sends browser notifications, and I know how to check the browser permission for the notifications, and how to request permissions if they are not granted.
However, even if the user granted permission for my site to send notifications, she might still not get the notifications, because they [might be disabled](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-notification-settings-in-windows-10-ddcbbcd4-0a02-f6e4-fe14-6766d850f294) (either globally on Windows, or for the current browser).

Is there a way for me to detect this and let the user know that notifications won't be displayed unless she enables them in **Windows Settings**?

Comment: I think that it would be a great security problem, whether you would be able to retrieve data of the OS from a browser..

Answer (score 4):

### There's no way to do it!

There's no way to do this, JavaScript doesn't have direct access to Windows to detect settings, or to change Windows settings.

I am pretty sure it's made to protect users' privacy.

### The only affected browsers by Windows settings are Chromium-built browsers.

If you turn notifications settings off in Windows, Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge (aka [*Chromium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)) browsers) won't be able to send notifications while other browsers like Firefox that are built on different engines will be able to send notifications.

This means that Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge uses a different way to send notifications:

Google Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome]

Microsoft Edge:

[image: Microsoft Edge]

While Firefox has a completely different way and UI:

[image: Firefox]

### Summarize:

JavaScript can't detect whether notification settings are enabled or not in Windows settings. And if notification settings are disabled, browsers like Firefox can still send notifications.